# how to populate selected option inside a input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have div container with `class="input-group"` i am having input field with drop down, which i am creating with the help of bootstrap4
what i am trying to do is when user clicks on any dropdown the selected option should gets populate inside that respective input field

**Code Snippet**

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <hr>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
        <label for="itemCode">Item Code</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item Code 1</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item Code 2</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item Code 3</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
        <label for="brandCode">Brand Code</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Brand Code 1</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Brand Code 2</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Brand Code 3</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

i have tried the onclick event but id dosn't print any values

How can i do this is there any easy way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
$(".dropdown-item").click(function() {
  $(this).closest(".input-group").find("input").val($(this).text())
});
```

**Working demo**

```js
$(".dropdown-item").click(function() {
  $(this).closest(".input-group").find("input").val($(this).text())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <hr>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
        <label for="itemCode">Item Code</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item Code 1</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item Code 2</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item Code 3</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
        <label for="brandCode">Brand Code</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Brand Code 1</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Brand Code 2</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Brand Code 3</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```